# Understanding method calls in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two classes

```
class Cart
  belongs_to :coupon
end

class Coupon
  has_many :carts

  def discount
  end
end
```

I execute

```
cart = Cart.last.coupon.discount
```

How can I know which cart it is within the discount method without passing cart as a parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by "which cart it is without passing cart as a parameter"?

Comment: by the problem description whatever you are trying to achieve - most likely you approach it wrong

Comment: @AndreyDeineko what I feel is that it shouldn't be Cart.last.coupon.discount(cart.last)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't from coupon. I'd suggest you delegate discount within cart.

```
class Cart
  belongs_to :coupon
  delegate :discount, to: coupon
end

class Coupon
  has_many :carts

  def discount
  end
end
```

Then you can

```
discount = cart.discount
```

However, note that delegate is a rails method. I assume that, as you are using belongs_to and tagged ruby-on-rails, you are within rails. However if not, this would also work:

```
class Cart
  belongs_to :coupon

  def discount
    coupon.discount if coupon
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

That would have been my approach:

```
class Cart
  belongs_to :coupon

  def discount
    coupon.discount(self) unless coupon.nil?
  end
end

class Coupon
  has_many :carts

  def discount(cart)
    # use the coupon discount logic to apply discount on particular cart
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done, AFAIK, and even if you could, it would be a horrible and brittle hack. When you're in the discount method you don't have access anymore to the specific Cart, only all the carts associated with the coupon. If that's just one cart, you're in luck.

What I would suggest, also in order to reduce coupling and to better comply with Demeter's Law, would be to create a discount method on the Cart

```
def discount 
  coupon.discount(self)
end
```

Another option could perhaps be having another ActiveRecord class, let's call it CouponActivation, sitting in the middle, that associates carts and coupons, and calculates the discount itself.

Cart belongs to CouponActivation, CouponActivation has one cart and belongs to Coupon, Coupon has many CouponActivations and many Carts through CouponActivations. You put the discount method in CouponActivation and have access to the information you want.

It's still advisable to just pass values around. Easier, clearer, easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

I think that approach you taken is not good.
If Coupon is object, which can give you a discount on Total price of Cart, then I would use this:

```
class Cart
  has_and_belongs_to_many :coupons

  def calculate_discount
    #this is place where you can get rid of double coupons or coupons that are not allowed together
    for coupon in coupons
      coupon.apply_discount_to(self)
    end
  end
end

class Coupon
  has_and_belongs_to_many :carts
end
```